# VB ASP .NET MVC Custom Membership Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

All of the examples I've found are in C# and I need one if VB.  How can I turn my code below to inherit all of the Membership provider functions?

```
Imports System.Data.Entity
Imports MyBlog

Namespace MyBlog

    Public Class EmployeeController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As EmployeeDbContext = New EmployeeDbContext

        '
        ' GET: /Employee/LogOn

        Public Function LogOn() As ActionResult
            Return View()
        End Function

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Here are the articles that I've read [Custom membership or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496779/custom-membership-or-not), [Implementing custom login for ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641779/implementing-custom-login-for-asp-net-mvc).  I can't seem to inherit more than one class in VB (don't often use inheritance or implement or interfaces).

Comment: Classes are not interfaces and .NET do not support multi-inheritance

Comment: Why would you want your controller to inherit the Membership class? Normally you'd just call the static methods such as "Membership.ValidateUser(...)" from within your controller methods.

Comment: That is what I am gathering.  How can I create a membership provider?  Must I omit the system.web.mvc.controller?  Or should I create a membership provider in a separate file and then import it on my controller?  This is more of a question of design.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking and what problem you have encountered. You don't know how to write a class that derives from [`MembershipProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) and override its methods? You have problems with VB.NET syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write a class that inherits from [MembershipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) and override the methods you are interested in:

```
Public Class MyCustomMembershipProvider
    Inherits System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider

    Public Overrides Property ApplicationName As String
        Get

        End Get
        Set(value As String)

        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ChangePassword(username As String, oldPassword As String, newPassword As String) As Boolean

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(username As String, password As String, newPasswordQuestion As String, newPasswordAnswer As String) As Boolean

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CreateUser(username As String, password As String, email As String, passwordQuestion As String, passwordAnswer As String, isApproved As Boolean, providerUserKey As Object, ByRef status As System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function DeleteUser(username As String, deleteAllRelatedData As Boolean) As Boolean

    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EnablePasswordReset As Boolean
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property EnablePasswordRetrieval As Boolean
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function FindUsersByEmail(emailToMatch As String, pageIndex As Integer, pageSize As Integer, ByRef totalRecords As Integer) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function FindUsersByName(usernameToMatch As String, pageIndex As Integer, pageSize As Integer, ByRef totalRecords As Integer) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetAllUsers(pageIndex As Integer, pageSize As Integer, ByRef totalRecords As Integer) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUserCollection

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetNumberOfUsersOnline() As Integer

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetPassword(username As String, answer As String) As String

    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetUser(providerUserKey As Object, userIsOnline As Boolean) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser

    End Function

    Public Overloads Overrides Function GetUser(username As String, userIsOnline As Boolean) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetUserNameByEmail(email As String) As String

    End Function

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts As Integer
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters As Integer
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property MinRequiredPasswordLength As Integer
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PasswordAttemptWindow As Integer
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PasswordFormat As System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordFormat
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property PasswordStrengthRegularExpression As String
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property RequiresQuestionAndAnswer As Boolean
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property RequiresUniqueEmail As Boolean
        Get

        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ResetPassword(username As String, answer As String) As String

    End Function

    Public Overrides Function UnlockUser(userName As String) As Boolean

    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub UpdateUser(user As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ValidateUser(username As String, password As String) As Boolean

    End Function
End Class
```

And then you register your custom provider in web.config:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MyMembership">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add 
            name="MyMembership" 
            type="MvcApplication1.MyCustomMembershipProvider, MvcApplication1" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" 
        />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Now from within your controllers you simply use the `Membership` class. For example in your `LogOn` action that was generated by the default template when you created your project you don't need to change absolutely anything:

```
<HttpPost()> _
Public Function LogOn(ByVal model As LogOnModel, ByVal returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then
        If Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password) Then
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe)
            If Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) AndAlso returnUrl.Length > 1 AndAlso returnUrl.StartsWith("/") _
               AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("//") AndAlso Not returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\") Then
                Return Redirect(returnUrl)
            Else
                Return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")
            End If
        Else
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.")
        End If
    End If

    ' If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    Return View(model)
End Function
```

All calls to `Membership` will now use your custom membership provider that you registered in web.config.

Comment: In MVC, where should the class go?  Then, how do I use the class back in my controller to perform actions such as LogOn (just like the "stock" membership provider)?

Comment: You could place this class in a sub-folder of your project. For example `Providers`. From your controller you simply use for example `Membership.ValidateUser("username", "password")`. I have updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Thanks, I hope this won't be too difficult.  Is the ApplicationName necessary to override or can I leave that out?

Comment: You can leave that out. But throw a `NotImplementedException` from all methods that you intend leaving out. It will be easier to debug problems later. Unfortunately Visual Studio didn't generate them for me when I implemented the abstract class, which is something it automatically does with C#. I don't know why it didn't do it with VB.NET but make sure you do it and don't leave those methods blank.

Answer (score 1):

I got an easier solution. Use nuget to install `griffin.mvccontrib`. Then create a new class like this:

```
public class MyAccountRepository implements IAccountRepository
end class
```

Press `CTRL+.` on the interface to import the correct namespace. The press `CTRL+.` on the class name to get all methods with their descriptions.

Then simply implement them using your `EmployeeDBContext`.

by doing so, you can leave everything else as is (using the standard internet MVC template)

Instruction: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/

Comment: Thank you, jgauffin.  As a contractor, I am handing this system off when I'm done, so I would rather make it as simple as possible.  This looks like a good solution, but I think the other solution by Darin will be easier to understand for future administrators of my code.

Comment: Implementing a membership provider properly is not trivial. Good luck.